# How I can do to recover a part of content

Tags: node.js

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {

    console.log(socket.pseudo + ' me parle ! Il me dit : ' + message);

  amqp.connect('amqp://user:pass@192.168.99.10:55672',    function(err, conn) {


var ok = conn.createChannel(message);
 function message(err, ch) {
q="message";
if (err != null) bail(err);
ch.assertQueue(q);
ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
 if (msg !== null) {
   **console.log(msg.content.toString());**
   ch.ack(msg);
 }
 });
 }
 });

    }); 
});


server.listen(8080);
```

this is my problem
 it retrieves all content
But I need just a Body 
**"Bienvenue !
Merci de vous etre inscris membre n : 268563.**

[image]